# How to filter out similar paths among several walking paths

Tags: python, routes, artificial-intelligence, polyline

I'm making a walking application.
Currently, the walking paths are stored in the form of latlng and image in db.
I want to show you the recommended trail, but I don't see a similar route, but I want to show you a representative route.
Is there a way to compare the paths and find out the similarity?

Below are the data formats and images.

latlng
 `[[{"latitude":40.6625196,"longitude":160.0643335},{"latitude":40.6625196,"longitude":160.0643335},{"latitude":40.6624447,"longitude":160.0643596},{"latitude":40.6624728,"longitude":160.0642969},{"latitude":40.6624549,"longitude":160.0643386},{"latitude":40.662504,"longitude":160.0643342},{"latitude":40.6624306,"longitude":160.0643851},{"latitude":40.6624852,"longitude":160.064349},{"latitude":40.6624376,"longitude":160.0643684},{"latitude":40.6624094,"longitude":160.0644189}]]`

images
[image]

I'm thinking about using Python to compare.

Comment: Which paths do you consider similar? You need some kind of definition to proceed.

Comment: @Dimitrius I'm making a tracking application. When users take a walk, the trail is stored in DB in the form of an image and LatLng.
My application has a function called a recommended trail, and I want to show only the representative image by filtering the similar-looking trails conducted in the same place instead of showing all the trails here.